# Visual 2012 live templates - Is it possible to define own?

Tags: web-applications, ide, visual-studio-2012, live-templates

Like in question. Is it possible to define own `'live templates'` like example in `WebStorm`, where after define that template I can use it later by press tab. Below screen from `Webstorm`:
[image: Live examples in Webstorm]

Can you tell me where is that option if exist? I'm googling and can't find any information so I add question here.

*P.S. Correct me if it's called otherwise. I copy this name from `WebStorm`*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for [Code Snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms165392%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? (`Tools` -> `Code Snippets Manager` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>)

Comment: It's look like something I was want. Also here is nice snippets editor: http://snippeteditor.codeplex.com/